# Problems connecting to the api in my react native project built with expo in production

Tags: react-native

I built an application as react native using expo, I tested it in development and it works well on all the devices I tested. But in production, it only works and interacts with the api on a single phone. I tested the build on other phones, the app opens but doesn't get the data from the api, it's as if it wasn't communicating with the api, but there's only one phone that it can register and get the data from the api

I've tried it on several other phones and had no success. I tried it on the same api, but hosted locally, and the result was the same. At first I thought it was because the api was built with http and https.